# The column name id was not found in this ResultSet. I do not need this column in my select

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

my repository:

```
   @Query(value="SELECT t1.foraPonta,t2.ponta,t1.data_medicao From " +
            "((SELECT Sum(ativo_c) AS foraPonta, data_medicao FROM my_table WHERE " +
            "unidade_id = :unidade_id AND (data_medicao >= :dataInicial AND " +
            "data_medicao <= :dataFinal) AND (hora_do_dia >=18 and hora_do_dia <= 20) " +
            "GROUP BY data_medicao  ORDER BY data_medicao ASC)) AS t1,((SELECT Sum(ativo_c) " +
            "as Ponta, data_medicao FROM pc.web_listar_medidas WHERE unidade_id = :unidade_id " +
            "AND (data_medicao >= :dataInicial AND data_medicao <= :dataFinal " +
            "AND ((hora_do_dia >=0 and hora_do_dia <=17) or (hora_do_dia >=21 and hora_do_dia <=23))) " +
            "GROUP BY data_medicao  ORDER BY data_medicao ASC)) AS t2 WHERE t2.data_medicao = t1.data_medicao " +
            "ORDER BY t2.data_medicao ASC;", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Medidas> listarPeriodoForaPonta(@Param("unidade_id") Integer unidade_id,
                                         @Param("dataInicial") Date dataInicial,
                                         @Param("dataFinal") Date dataFinal );
```

my controller:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd")
    @GetMapping("/medidas/periodo/{unidade_id}/{dataInicial}/{dataFinal}")
    List<Medidas> listaMedidasPeriodo(@PathVariable("unidade_id") Integer unidade_id, @PathVariable("dataInicial") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date dataInicial, @PathVariable("dataFinal") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date dataFinal) {
        List<Medidas> medidas = medidasRepositorio.listarMedidasPeriodo(unidade_id, dataInicial, dataFinal);
        return medidas;
    }
```

Error message:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.

I need to list exactly I wrote in sql query and I do not wanna id column. What I missing?

Comment: Add your `Medidas` class

Comment: @Dennis
 I guess your Medidas class is expecting id which is not present in your result set. If you don't want to have id as part of your result set, then you can write custom Projection class to map the resultset

Comment: my Medidas class
-Entity
-Table(name="my_table", schema="my_schema")
-NoArgsConstructor
-AllArgsConstructor
-Data
public class Medidas {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id_medidas")
 private Integer id_medidas;

Comment: Use Class-Based Projections see details here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#class-based-projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But from what i can see, you need to make a DTO class with a constructor like

```
package my.package.dtos;

class MyDTO {
    BigDecimal foraPonta;
    BigDecimal ponta;
    Date data_medicao;

    public MyDTO(BigDecimal foraPonta, BigDecimal ponta, Date data_medicao){
        this.foraPonta = foraPonta;
        this.ponta = ponta;
        this.data_medicao = data_medicao;
    }
    public MyDTO(Double foraPonta, Double ponta, Date data_medicao){
        this(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(foraPonta)), new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(ponta)), data_medicao);
    }

}
```

By the way, i'm just guessing the types of `foraPonta`, `ponta` and `data_medicao`

And your query should look something like

```
SELECT new my.package.dtos.MyDTO(t1.foraPonta,t2.ponta,t1.data_medicao) From ...
```

Comment: I removed the first line of your answer. Someone had already added the request for the DTO class to the comments.

Comment: Thank you...I could solve this problem using this answer.

Comment: @Dennis you can mark is as the answer if it worked, i'm glad i could help

Answer (score -1):

My first step would be to double check that the Medidas class has the properties corresponding to the column names, and all properties marked as mandatory in Medidas are in the set of the returned columns:

```
foraPonta
ponta
data_medicao
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This shouldn't be an answer. It should be a comment. Answers are reserved for solutions to problems. It may be deleted soon.